# Как можно уменьшить количество цифр

Tags: php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-rub"));
$price  = $data->ticker->price;
echo $price
```

Answer (score 1):

```
number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," ) : string
```